# Sphinx Autoflask - Differentiate docstrings for GET and POST requests on same function

Tags: python, flask, python-sphinx

I have a Flask application I am working on building documentation for via python-sphinx.

I am currently using the autoflask extension from `sphinxcontrib.autohttp.flask`

My question is : How can I prepare a docstring, which properly applies different information to a GET version and POST version of the same route.

For instance a small function :

```
@app.route('/add_event', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_event():
    """
    ..http:get:: /add_event
        :return: Test
    ..http:post:: /add_event
        :return: Test2
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # get some things
        person_id = request.args.get('id')
        return render_template('create_event.html', race_event_form=test_form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # post some things

        return redirect('/person_profile/id/{0}'.format(request.args.get('id')))
```

My current extensions in conf.py

```
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.ifconfig',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
    'sphinx.ext.githubpages',
    'sphinxcontrib.httpdomain',
    'sphinxcontrib.autohttp.flask',
    'sphinxcontrib.autohttp.flaskqref'
]
```

The sphinx output looks like

[image]

Is it possible to right one thing for a GET and another for a POST? Id really like to avoid splitting every function into two separate get / post functions.

Also, is it possible to have autoflask ouput required arguments passed through `request.args` or `request.form` like the `person_id` variable in the GET request ?

Comment: did you ever work this out?

Comment: I did not, circled away from the project :/ Ill look back at it shortly when I get some time away from new project. Thanks for input

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the overloaded view function from Flask autodoc and define the requests individually, while leaving the rest of your API to be automatically generated.

Here's an example...

In `conf.py` (order of plugins ***is*** important):

```
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinxcontrib.httpdomain',
    'sphinxcontrib.autohttp.flask',
]
```

In reStructuredText file:

```
API
===

.. autoflask:: path.to.your:app
  :undoc-static:
  :undoc-endpoints: your_view_method

.. http:get:: / your_view_endpoint

  Some docstring you wrote.

.. http:post:: / your_view_endpoint

  Another docstring you wrote.
```

With regards to your second question, you might look at the directives for `httpdomain` [here](https://pythonhosted.org/sphinxcontrib-httpdomain/#directives).